# Is It Possible for a number that is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE for both Integers?

Tags: java

```
int x = ?;
if(x > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

when the above condition gets true??? what is the value of x?
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff, I tried x with 0x80000000 in hexa decimal. But x is now negative number.

Comment: There is no such `int x`. That's by definition of `MAX_VALUE`

Comment: I am asking what x values possible in that condition. Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2 power of 31 -1.

Comment: I'll repeat what I said: no value of `x` (if `x` is an `int`) will cause the condition `x > Integer.MAX_VALUE` to be true.

Comment: possible value of x to satisfy the condition(true)

Comment: Do you not understand what I'm telling you? The answer is, "**This is not possible.**"

Comment: Lol ,  there is no such value. Thats what @pkpnd is telling you.

Comment: No way to make this possible???

Comment: May I ask why you need this?

Comment: https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/CodedInputStream.java#L2716 can u check thie code if (byteLimit > currentLimit)

Comment: @AshokMutyala **NO**. You can not have a number greater than the _max value_. It's called that for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Java integers are 32-bit, and anything above the maximum value for a 32-bit number will get rolled over and become negative. This is known as integer overflow.

If you have:

```
int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
x += 1;
```

`x` will equal `-2147483648`, or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such `x`.

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **int**: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a **maximum**
>   **value of 2^31-1**.

That max 32-bit value is equal to `0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

It's a [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, so setting the 1st bit to 1 will result to a negative number (0x80000000 = 1000..0000). So, there's really no possible value for the `x` you're looking for.